# How do I add questions and answers to my quiz application in a practical way?

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am going to develop a quiz app and I am new to it.

I added 2 questions into the file named questions_example.dart

I created the quiz questions and answers as follows. I set correct answers as true, wrong answers as false ;

```
List<QuestionModel> questions = [
  QuestionModel(
    "Ünlü olmak ister miydin? Ne şekilde ?",
    {
      "1": false,
      "3": false,
      "Asla": true,
      "5,007": false,
    },
  ),
  QuestionModel("Telefon görüşmelerinden önce ne konuşacağını tasarlar mısın? Neden? ?", {
    "When it cares for its kittens": false,
    "When it needs confort": false,
    "When it feels content": false,
    "Tasarlamam": true,
  }),
```

Finally, I made my quiz application as seen in the pictures;

[image]

[image]

I need to add new questions and answers to the application. It takes me a long time to write these questions one by one into the questions_example.dart file. What would you suggest for a shortcut? As a result of my research, it seems appropriate to add questions over firebase. Is there a way you would suggest?

Example; Can I create a panel within the application that only I can access? Can I add or subtract questions and answers online from here?

Comment: Can I create a panel within the application that only I can access? Can I add or subtract questions and answers online from here? yes that it

Comment: @lava 
Yes that it, is it possible to add new questions that other users will see with the help of that panel?

Comment: yes  using firebase you can easily do .other wise you can use restapi.or you can use sqlite with supplay a bulk question answer while you publish your app.

Comment: @lava 
Thank you, "rest-api" and "sqlite" I will check these

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you first focus on your questions and answers and write them in text files on your own computer. Work on those until you feel they are 100% ready.

Then create a simple Firebase project and store your questions and answers in documents on Firebase and connect your application to Firebase to read the contents of those questions.

Answer (score 0):

- write the questions in notepads++

My first suggestions is write the questions in the notepad ++ when you feel like having enough questions copies them to your list of questions.

- Create a database

My second suggestions will be connect your quiz app to a backend then at any time with our updating your app you can add questions directly to the db.